# Object with users, remove all but one when 2 values match (firstname, lastname)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I want to create a new object, where the users should only appear once.
So if a person appears multiple times, which is given when `given_name` and `family_name` both match, all but one are removed.

Example:

```
 [
      {
        given_name: 'Aha',
        family_name: 'Yes',
        email: 'Yes@gmail.com',
      },
      {
        given_name: 'Testname',
        family_name: 'Test',
        email: 'Testname@gmail.com',
      },
     {
        given_name: 'Hans',
        family_name: 'Test',
        email: 'Testname@gmail.com',
      },
     {
        given_name: 'Aha',
        family_name: 'Yes',
        email: 'Yesassss@gmail.com',
      }
    ]
```

So the above should result in this:

```
[
      {
        given_name: 'Aha',
        family_name: 'Yes',
        email: 'Yes@gmail.com',
      },
      {
        given_name: 'Testname',
        family_name: 'Test',
        email: 'Testname@gmail.com',
      },
     {
        given_name: 'Hans',
        family_name: 'Test',
        email: 'Testname@gmail.com',
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Why is the second Aha removed and not the first?

Comment: It doesnt matter for me which one is removed, I just need all users (firstname, lastname) without duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below one liner code

```js
let arr = arr.filter((item,index)=>arr.findIndex(item2=>(item.family_name == item2.family_name && item.given_name == item2.given_name))>=index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, here we are using a map to get the unique values. For the keys in the map, we use a combination of `given_name` and `family_name`.

```js
const users = [{given_name: "Aha", family_name: "Yes", email: "Yes@gmail.com"}, {given_name: "Testname", family_name: "Test", email: "Testname@gmail.com"}, {given_name: "Hans", family_name: "Test", email: "Testname@gmail.com"}, {given_name: "Aha", family_name: "Yes", email: "Yesassss@gmail.com"}];

const removeDuplicates = (data) => {
   const userNameMap = {};
   data.forEach((user) => {
       const userName = `${user.given_name}|${user.family_name}`;
       userNameMap[userName] = user;
   });

   return Object.values(userNameMap);
};

console.log(removeDuplicates(users));
```